# Capture strings inside escaped quotes

Tags: python, regex, presto

I have 3 strings in this format

```
Bank: {"955974044748481":["BANK_A"]}
{"reason": "Bank: {"455049295219902":["BANK_B"]}"}
{"reason": "Bank: {\\"1876212592475597\\":[\\"BANK_C\\"]}"}
```

I need to extract the `bank_id` and `bank_name` from these strings using a single regex in a presto SQL statement.

I have tried this regex but it only captures the first two and not the last one which has escape characters. https://regex101.com/r/ejW68x/1

```
Bank: {"(.*)":\["(.*)"\]}
```

What's the right way to capture all 3 variations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
Bank:.*{(?:\\\\)?"([^{"]*?)(?:\\\\)?":\[(?:\\\\)?"(.*?)(?:\\\\)?"\]}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RcoDsV/1).

Or to make sure the `\\` are only matched in pairs:

```
Bank:.*{((?:\\\\)?)"([^{"]*?)\1":\[((?:\\\\)?)"(.*?)\3"\]}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/08wQ0Z/1).

Note that in the second case, your captures will be in groups #2 and #4.

---

### Update:

Your new test strings would still be matched by the above patterns. You may just replace `Bank:.*` with `Bank:[ ]` if you like. [**Demo1**](https://regex101.com/r/RcoDsV/2) - [**Demo2**](https://regex101.com/r/08wQ0Z/3).

### Explanaion: <sup>(changes to your pattern)</sup>

- Added `(?:\\\\)?` --> An optional non-capturing group to match the two backslash characters.
- Replaced your first capturing group `(.*)` with `([^{"]*?)` to avoid matching double-quote and `{` characters (this is especially necessary for your first test strings). Also, converted it from greedy to lazy (by adding `?`) to avoid capturing the escaping characters (`\\`) if present.
- Made the second capturing group lazy as well `(.*?)` for the same reason.
- In the second pattern, `(?:\\\\)?` was added to a capturing group so that a backreference can be used (i.e., `\1` and `\3`). The purpose of this is to only match if both the double-quote characters are escaped (preceded by `\\`).

Comment: I have updated the test strings to be more precise...I just need to look for 'Bank' word and then followed by ID and Name inside flower backets (with or without escape chars)

Comment: @user330612 Your updated test strings make part of the patterns above unnecessary but it will still work. Do you need to support the original test strings or not?

Comment: I dont need to support the original test string..sorry for the confusion. If the regex can be more cleaner to match the new test strings, that would be great. thanks for the help. Also a bit of explanation on what the regex is doing is appreciated

Comment: @user330612 On second thought, I would still use the same patterns (no need to get rid of the `[^{"]` part. You may just replace `Bank:.*` with `Bank[ ]` if you like. I will add an explanation though.